# How to send message from Bot to multiple-client in Bot framework

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

Greeting every one! I'm new at Microsoft Bot Framework and I want to know that how can we send message from Bot to multiple client (not using chat group)? Please give me some advices. Thanks
One more question is how can we save the conversation between Bot and Client when client close their Browser in order to retrieve the conversation when client come back another time?

Comment: chk out this link https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the docs I think there is a method `CreateConversation()` method for sending emails to multiple clients.

But I think you can use `CreateDirectConversation()` method in a for loop, iterating over your user accounts. This will initiate 1:1 conversation with all user accounts.

Comment: That's a good idea, thank friend!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Microsoft Bot Framwork SDK Reference: Starting Conversations](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/routing#conversation)

---

### Starting Conversations

To initiate a conversation you need to call the `CreateConversation()` or `CreateDirectConversation()` methods to get a `ConversationAccount` record from the channel. Once you have the `ConversationAccount` can use it in a message call to `SendToConversation()`.

---

### Create 1:1 Conversations

The `CreateDirectConversation()` method is used to create a private 1:1 conversation between the bot and the user.

To initialize a `ConnectorClient` you use `ServiceUrl` persisted from previous messages

Example:

```
var userAccount = new ChannelAccount(name: "Larry", id: "@UV357341");
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(incomingMessage.ServiceUrl));
var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateDirectConversationAsync(botAccount, userAccount);
IMessageActivity message =  Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = userAccount;
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
message.Text = "Hello";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

---

### Create Group Conversations

The `CreateConversation()` method is used to create a new group conversation.

> **NOTE: Currently Email is the only channel which supports bot initiated group conversations**

Example:

```
var connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(incomingMessage.ServiceUrl));
List<ChannelAccount> participants = new List<ChannelAccount>();
participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("joe@contoso.com", "Joe the Engineer"));
participants.Add(new ChannelAccount("sara@contso.com", "Sara in Finance"));
ConversationParameters cpMessage = new ConversationParameters(message.Recipient, true, participants, "Quarter End Discussion");
var conversationId = await connector.Conversations.CreateConversationAsync(cpMessage);
IMessageActivity message = Activity.CreateMessageActivity();
message.From = botAccount;
message.Recipient = new ChannelAccount("lydia@contoso.com", "Lydia the CFO"));
message.Conversation = new ConversationAccount(id: conversationId.Id);
message.ChannelId = incomingMessage.ChannelId;
message.Text = "Hey, what's up everyone?";
message.Locale = "en-Us";
await connector.Conversations.SendToConversationAsync((Activity)message);
```

Comment: actually, I didn't tend to create chat group. My situation here is the client chat with my bot and I want my bot to forwarding this message to another web application.

Comment: @JustinJT then you should say that clearly in your question.

Comment: okay, thanks for your help, it open up my mind. And How can we save the conversation before the client close the browser in order to retrieve the previous conversation if client return again? Do you have any idea?

Comment: @JustinJT I could update the answer if you like. Maybe you can edit your question?

Comment: I've just done it